# MVC, Get MasterPage path from inside a view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, master-pages

How can i get the path of the MasterPage from inside a view, I tought that

```
((WebFormView)Html.ViewContext.View).MasterPath
```

would do the trick, but unfortunately, it's always empty.

so how do I get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm nto sure what you need exactly, but the View should have a MasterPageFile property that contains the relative path to the MasterPage.  You can use MapPath if you need the physical location.

```
<%= this.MasterPageFile %>

<%= MapPath( this.MasterPageFile ) %>
```