# MVC RenderAction Areas and MasterPages

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I have a MVC application, using areas and a masterpage. I have a single MasterPage i'd like to use in all areas placed in PRJ\Views\Shared.
My master page have several RenderAction calls to actions inside a controller in my root PRG Controllers folder.
Everything works great if i'm referencing the masterpage from my views folder but not for my views inside the areas. I guess it expects the controllers and actions to be inside the Areas!!!.

Please help-me in this one.

Thank U all.

Comment: MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/master.master" <-- doesn't it work??

Comment: may be it'll help
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/635941/mvc-get-masterpage-path-from-inside-a-view

Comment: 3nigma: The problem is (i think) MVC is mapping the Action to Controllers inside Areas not the Controllers inside the "root" Controllers. Well... i think that!!!!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use

```
@Html....("A Link", "Action", "Controller", new { Area = "" }, null);
```

This will always point to an area-less controller/action